# How does game center works offline?

Tags: ios, game-center

Is there a caching mechanism in game center that can be used offline? Is it possible that game center collects the scores in offline mode and when network status is changed to online it delivers the scores to server? Is it possible to read the downloaded scores in offline mode?

If answer of above questions are NO, is there a library that could do this for us?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Axeva's answer is incorrect** - [GKLocalPlayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKLocalPlayer_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009587) defines no such method as "resubmitStoredScores". Rather, this method is defined and implemented in [example code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/GKLeaderboards/Introduction/Intro.html) provided on Apple's iOS Developer Library which demonstrates the use of GameKit leaderboards.

If you don't want to copy the code from Apple's example, there are a few libraries out there. Some googling turned up the following hits on github.com:

- /anton-nikan/iOS-Game-Center-Cache
- /csddavies/DDGameKitHelper

If none of those satisfies your needs, you'll need to implement your own solution.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Game Center will cache scores.  There is a resubmitStoredScores method for the GKLocalPlayer object that you call in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions of your app delegate.

Here is an example:

```
    GKLocalPlayer *localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];

    [[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] authenticateWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
        if (localPlayer.isAuthenticated) {
            // Enable Game Center Functionality 
            self.gameCenterAuthenticationComplete = YES;

            if (! self.currentPlayerID || ! [self.currentPlayerID isEqualToString: localPlayer.playerID]) {
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool: NO forKey: kGameInProgress];

                // Switching Users 
                if (!self.player || ![self.currentPlayerID isEqualToString: localPlayer.playerID]) {
                    // If there is an existing player, replace the existing PlayerModel object with a 
                    // new object, and use it to load the new player's saved achievements.
                    // It is not necessary for the previous PlayerModel object to writes its data first;
                    // It automatically saves the changes whenever its list of stored 
                    // achievements changes.

                    self.player = [[[PlayerModel alloc] init] autorelease];                        
                }     
                [[self player] loadStoredScores];
                [[self player] resubmitStoredScores];
            }
        } else {
            // User has logged out of Game Center or can not login to Game Center, your app should run 
            // without GameCenter support or user interface. 
            self.gameCenterAuthenticationComplete = NO;
        }
    }];
```